# How do i get visual studio like tabs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, tabs

I've been thinking for a while in my head and I've not been able to find the solution to it ! Please help me.

I've always loved the visual studio tabs and how they look. They're small and perfect. The normal .NET TabControl, well is plain and boring! I've seen these tabs being used in many applications. My question is:

> Is there a DLL that is available that has this kind of tabcontrol?

Here's a picture for reference:

[image: Visual Studio Tabs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need "DockPanel Suite by mtwombley, spudcud, weifenluo".

It's an awsome open-source project, and you can get it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing.  A tab control with VS-like tabs.

DocPanel Suite is great, but it's like filling a hole with a bulldozer.  Here is an extension of the existing tab control that does what I was looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition

Answer (score 0):

found this googling
http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3266

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a great TabStrip product whether you are looking for [WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/tabstrip.aspx), [WebForms](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/appearance/customcssclasses/defaultcs.aspx), [WPF](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/resources/demo-requirements.aspx), [Silverlight](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Home), or [MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip). All of these tabs can be customized and they come with some great default styles, you can find many more (including some VS templates) online, or you can create your own, which isn't that hard. They even provide [a tool to help you create your own](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/visual-style-builder.aspx). Some of their products cost money and some are free, so it depends on what you're looking for.